# Best practice for parsing and displaying wysiwyg code

Tags: php

I have a wysiwg on my website that allows users to use

```
<br/>, <p>, <a>, <img>,<span>, <b>, <i>
```

What is the best way to only allow these these types of tags to display on the page, would a strip tags be sufficient, or regex?

I'm trying to disallow things like

```
<html>, <script>, <?php ?>
```

etc from running.

Or should I use htmlentities, and then str_replace the certain html codes I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) does exactly what you want.

Def:

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

Usage for your case:

```
strip_tags($text, '<br><p><a><img><span><b><i>');
```

You don't need to strip `<?php` and `?>` unless you're using `eval()` function on this string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) for this. It will let you specify which HTML elements are allowed in a string and will strip out all the other.

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) does the job easy.